# How to return one of two types in a getter method?

Tags: java

I'm trying to program a board for a game. The board has 25 fields, and each field can either contain a base or 4 different sizes of rings.

```
public class Field {

    private Base base;
    private Ring[] rings;

    public Object getPieces() {
        if (base == null) {
            return rings;
        } else {
            return base;
        }
    }

}
```

I programmed the setter methods so that a `Base` only can be set if `rings` is null, and that a `Ring` only can be set if `base` is null.

The problem is that in order to paint the board, my view needs the contents of `Field`, which is either a `Base` or a `Ring[]`. I find it hard, however, to allow the method to return both types. Right now, I'm returning the contents as Object, but this is bad practice.

Is there any way in which I can allow my method to return both types?

If not, is there a way in which I can store my pieces more efficiently that allows me to return them as one type?

Also, `Base` and `Ring` both extends the same superclass `Piece`, so I could return them as pieces instead, but then I would still have the problem that one of the two return types is an array where the other is not.

Comment: Shouldn't you introduce a super class for both then? Add a superclass `Piece` or whatever you like. Or use an `interface`

Comment: You could put your `Base`in an array, and always return a `Piece[]`. As an example : `return new Piece[]{base};`

Comment: Obviously you can't return two different classes. Either let both implement a common interface/extend from a superclass or create a wrapper class containing both elements, one set to `null` then. Alternatively rethink your design.

Comment: Why does your calling code need to know (at compile time) how many objects you return?

Comment: By the way, are you trying to create the game "Ringgz"? It was an assignment in my first year of Computer Science.

Comment: @PeterBruins jep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return an array of pieces. If you need to return only the base, then you just put it inside an array of pieces which will be the only element. Otherwise you return the array or rings.

So, your method will be like this:

```
public Piece[] getPieces() {
     Piece [] toReturn;
     if (base == null) {
         toReturn = rings;
     } else {
         toReturn = new Piece[]{base};
     }
     return toReturn;
}
```

Consider that if you implemented new methods in the `Base` or `Ring` classes, then those methods can´t be called because you defined that the objets inside the array are from the `Piece` class, unless you make a cast - if the array has only one element it is a Base, otherwise is a Ring. This is like an `implicit instanceOf`, so be very carefull. The use of `instanceOf` should make you check if there is a better way of solving the problem!

Answer (score 0):

In the class where you are calling your getter, you could try using the instanceOf

```
Field field = new Field();
Object returnObject = field.getPieces();
if(returnObject instanceOf Base){
// add to Base
} else if(returnObject instanceOf Rings){
// add to rings
}
```

Unless you have a strict programming guidelines, in the long run the code can end extremely long and ugly, and after some point of time you might not be able to debug the code as well. So be careful.

I would say setting null is even a more "badder" practice than methods returning Object instances. As long as you can help it, don't set anything as null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out what you want to do with the things that this method returns and then create a superclass for them. This may be the `Piece` class, but it could be a `Drawable` or something else. Without knowing what you are doing it is hard to give a real answer.

As to your array or object you have two options. Again what is right for you is hard to give based on the information given. Either the `getPieces` can a collection of some sort regardless (array, List, Set etc) even if it is a collection of one, or your `Piece` (or `Drawable` or what ever) could work regardless of if what backs it is a single `Piece` or a collection of `Piece`s.

You should be attempting to encapsulate the logic rather than just handing things out willy-nilly. Again I don't know your application, but say in the case of a Bank rather than have a `getBalance` and `setBalance` you have a `deposit`, `withdraw` and `display(onThis)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your architecture propably violates the [Tell, Dont Ask principle](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html): The `Board` asks `Field` for it-s internal state `getPieces()`.

If you reformulate this to: The `Board` tells `Field` to draw itself you find out that the drawing logic should belong to `Field` and not to board. This way there is no more need for the board to know the implementations detail that a field may contain a base or rings.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the use the Model, View, Controller model, meaning the view should be seperate from the model (Board)